# Audio default randomly switches to output that doesn't have anything plugged into it

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones, spdif

I have 2 audio devices on my computer: an S/PDIF output and headphones. The headphones are the device i want it to output through, but it will randomly decide to set my default audio device to the S/PDIF connection. Why is this and how can i fix it? [can provide pictures if necessary]
OS = Windows 7 x64

Comment: If this is recent, think of any changes you may have made to the system or anything you've recently installed.

Comment: I've installed a few programs and screensavers, but nothing that should change the default. It's also happened in the past.

Comment: Does the default device change when the headphones are inserted/removed from the headphone jack?

Comment: I haven't plugged anything in in a long time...

Comment: to the jack i mean.

Comment: So we can assume you're using USB headphones, right?

Comment: Yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you disable the hardware device for the internal sound card (in Device Manager) when you use your USB headphones? A workaround I know, but since Windows 7 has already gone RTM...

Comment: um, how would i do this? i don't have much experience with that...

Comment: Open Computer Management (Start->Run, type `compmgmt.msc` and click OK) and then go to Device Manager. In there you'll see Sound, Video and Game Controllers. Expand that node and right click on the devices that are not your USB headset and disable them. It might take some experimentation to figure out exactly which one is your USB headset and which one is the internal sound card.